# Deleting multiple files in a directory using chef ruby

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, cookbook

I have been looking for a chef ruby code to delete multiple files in a directory matching on a file name string

Lets say if my D drive contains the file names - 
eula1.txt,
eula2.txt,
res1.dll,
res2.dll,
pvn1.txt,
pvn2.txt

In the above example, i would need a chef ruby code which i can include in the cookbook to delete all occurrences of a file starting with eula* and res*, i.e it should delete 4 files in the directory

My Final output should contain only 2 files - pvn1.txt,pvn2.txt in the directory.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to use an `execute` resource like:

```
execute 'del eula* res*'
```

While it is possible to do this with direct file deletion, it is much more complex and probably out of scope for you.

Answer (score 1):

I could use 'FileUtils' to delete the files with the matching condition. Since FileUtils is pure ruby command, i have to embed this code inside a ruby_block in my chef cookbook.

The below statement worked for me

```
ruby_block "Deleting the eula*,install* files...." do    
  block do    
    FileUtils.rm Dir["path/to/folder/eula*","path/to/folder/install*"]    
  end
end
```